# how to forward all requests to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to forward all http requests on my virtual host to an index.php file in my apache servers document root.

would the following .htacess file do that ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate of several others.

Comment: The answers here are better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310481/htaccess-redirecting-all-requests-to-domain-root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```