# Redirecting all RESTful requests to domain root without changing URL

Tags: .htaccess, rest, http, redirect

As the title says, I want all requests

```
domain.com/something
domain.com/somethting/else
domain.com/a/third/thing
```

to redirect to

```
domain.com
```

BUT still show the original URL since I want to use them as parameters. I've tried [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011737/redirect-all-to-base-domain) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310481/htaccess-redirecting-all-requests-to-domain-root) ideas but the URLs end up displaying

```
domain.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here at Gareth Jones's blog](http://blog.garethj.com/2009/02/17/building-a-restful-web-application-with-php/#singleScript):

**Passing all requests to a single PHP script**

I needed all requests with a certain URL prefix to be handled by a single script. This was easily solved using the following URL re-writing rule in a .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
```

Note that I had to enable the mod_rewrite module in Apache and ensure that directives could be overridden with the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

**Determining the full requested URL**

Another requirement of my application complicated by URL rewriting was that I needed access to the full URL. I achieved this with the following bit of code:

```
$protocol = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
$location = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {
  $location = substr($location, 0, strrpos($location, $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) - 1);
}
$url = $protocol.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$location;
```